# Password confirmation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to build a register form in laravel. My form has a password confirmation.
In the view I have following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
      <label for="password_confirmation">Confirm Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_confirmation" name="password">
</div>
```

And in the controller I have following code to validation:

```
$this->validate(request(), [
     'name' => 'required',
     'email' => 'required|email',
     'password' => 'required|confirmed',
 ]);
```

When I submit the form I get "The password confirmation does not match." error. What causes this error?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your password inputs have the same name: `password`. You need to rename the confirmation one: `name="password_confirmation"`

Answer (score 0):

**This is the best way to confirm your password in laravel**

```
<label class="control-label">Password</label>

            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>
            <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" onclick="myFunction()"> Show Hide</i>

                               {!! $errors->first('password', '
            <p class="text-danger errorBag" id="showerror">:message</p>') !!}
        </div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">

            <label class="control-label">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="myInput1" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control 
                            " value="{{old('password-confirm')}}">
                            <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" onclick="myFunction1()"> Show Hide</i> {!! $errors->first('password-confirm', '
            <p class="text-danger errorBag" id="showerror1">:message</p>') !!}
        </div>
```

**In Controller**

```
public function manage_vendorstore(Request $request)
{
     request()->validate([
    'password' => 'required|between:6,255|confirmed',
]);

$data = new Vendor();

$data->password = Hash::make($request->get('password'));
}
```

Comment: if password_confirmation must match password, then it must also have the same validation.